# Z-score calculation for a single variable with readings in multiple units

Tags: data-transformation, standardization, units

I ran into little trouble transforming a set of data I need for analysis. I have been trying to analyze results of a lab test as Z-scores. I have an output field with a reading and unit field. Data are shown in the figure below.

[image: Data Set]

The approach I followed was to convert this data to Z-scores by taking every individual subset of data for a unit. So one subset for the unit "IU/L", its SD, mean and subsequently its Z-scores were calculated. The same procedure was repeated for "g/L", "mmol/L", and the like.
The calculated Z-scores were then mapped back to the original readings.

Is this approach correct? And are there any work-arounds to reduce the effort this procedure consumes?

Comment: You did not provide the ultimate goal of the analysis nor any motivation for the need for $z$-scores.

Comment: The intent here is to be able to compare the "Results" data from a bunch of sources. It also gets utilized in PCA and repeat-value detection, amongst a few other preliminary tests.

Comment: I don't see how $z$-scores are relevant for that.  If the standard deviations differ you are then comparing different absolute effects, for one thing.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: The knowledge that Z-scores allow me to bring readings with different units on the same scale, was the motivation. I have also used the values to perform an outlier analysis (as a part of preliminary tests) for which I would need to have all my readings on a common scale. Hence the aforementioned approach.

Comment: By using $z$-scores with different standard deviations in different samples you are actually doing the analysis on different scales.  In addition, you are assuming the variables are Gaussian and that "badness" is equidistant from the mean.

Comment: Thanks for that take Frank Harrell. In your opinion, what would be the best approach to bring these values on a common scale?

Comment: Please expand on the need for having a common scale.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: The need for common scales is to be able to compare the results from all the labs generating the information. We are attempting to score these differnet sites on the basis of the quality of data that is being provided.The quality of information is being checked against some standard methods like a study of variance on the data, p-value calculation for missing balues and the like. For these calculations we need the values to be on a common scale. I could share some of the work I have done with you over an email, to help further clarify my approach.

Comment: It does not follow that standard deviations are the correct normalization constants.